# How to change a parsed text into integer or remove decimal points?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

How to convert a text into integer? The "reference_price" parsed from a webpage is "123.45" and its type is Text. However, I would like to change this to an integer like "123".

```
###### Parsing   
tbody = table.tbody
    for i, tr in enumerate(tbody.find_all('tr')):      
        reference_price = tr.find('td').text
    
###### Convert to datafrme 
reference_price_list = reference_price_list.append(reference_price)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(reference_price_list), columns=['price'])
```

I have tried both int("reference_price") and reference_price.astype(int) but doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to float first ? Then use the the int() conversion function of the floor() function ?

Comment: What if the returned _value/string_ by `find.text` is not a number-like ? Do we need to skip it ?

Comment: They are all number like 30060.0 1594.0 5.6 1819.5 6.4 4455.5 17.4 etc.

Comment: Are the values **guaranteed** to contain a decimal point?

Comment: yes! all values have two decimal points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, before you can cast `reference_price` to an (`int`), you need to make sure to retain only the whole number (*the left part of the decimal-like*). One way, is to use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with [*slicing*](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) :

```
reference_price_list = []

for tr in table.tbody.find_all("tr"):
    reference_price = (tr.find("td").text).split(".")[0]
    reference_prise = int(reference_prise.replace(",",""))
    reference_price_list.append(reference_price)

df = pd.DataFrame({"price": reference_price_list}) # <- df.dtypes|price:int64
```

*NB : You may need to include a* `try..except` *statement to catch an eventual* `ValueError`.

Comment: Thank you. but there's an error. Invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30,060': `reference_price = tr.find('td').text` `reference_price = int(reference_price.split(".")[0])` `mineral['reference_price'] = reference_price`

Comment: But in case the string is 30,060.00, I only need to remove decimal like 30,060. So I have added `reference_price = reference_price.replace(",", "")` before the line including `re.split`.

Comment: Yes, we can handle that, I updated my answer. Can you check it out ?